# How to add automatic filters to Excel output in Cognos reports?

Tags: html, excel, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I am working on a project in `Cognos Report Studio version 10.2.1`.
One of the business requirement is that the output format of the report should be in Excel 2007 with auto filter on the headers of the row.

I tried inserting one html item above the list and one below the list with the following code:

1st HTML code above the list:

```
 <table>
    <td x:autofilterrange="$A$1:$D$1" /td>
```

2nd HTML code below the list:

```
</table>
```

Can anyone please suggest where I am going wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: I haven't been able to get XML blocks like that working for a couple of versions of Cognos (or excel, can't remember which).  Really unhappy about it too.

Comment: Ok so there is no way I can do this right? I have been searching everywhere on forums/websites/articles but none had any solution to this...nd I wonder why? how a simple yet an important function can a Cognos afford to miss

Comment: Far as I know, you can't do it, no.

Comment: I was reading somewhere that we can use Macro to work this out. Anyone have a Macro code that I can put in cognos?